# ShellExecuteでcmd.exeからbat実行する際に引数にフォルダパスを入れたい

Tags: c++, mfc, cmd

ShellExecuteを使ってcmd.exeを呼び出し、batファイルを実行し、その際にフォルダパスを引数に入れたいのですが、batが正常に実行できません。

```
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "shell32.lib")

CString strCommand;
CString strPath;
strPath = "\"C:\\Sample Folder\\Test\""
strCommand = "/c \"C:\\Test\\Sample.bat\" " + strPath;
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "cmd.exe", strCommand, "", SW_SHOW);
```

引数のフォルダ名称に半角スペースがない場合で、パスの両端をダブルクォーテーションで括らない場合は動作するのですが、上記のように半角スペースが存在する場合も考えられるため、両端をダブルクォーテーションで括る必要があるのですが、その場合batが動作しません。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: これではないですか？ [cmd.exe /c の引数について (半角スペースと"の微妙な関係)](https://tunemicky.blogspot.com/2012/03/cmdexe-c.html) 「対処方法としては、/cの後に続く、コマンドラインを " でさらに括ります。」

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメント内容が該当したので以下の記事から引用して回答化(太字は引用者)：
[cmd.exe /c の引数について (半角スペースと"の微妙な関係)](https://tunemicky.blogspot.com/2012/03/cmdexe-c.html)

> 【実験2】
>   cmd.exeに/cでbatファイルを指定した場合
>   cmd.exe /c "c:\Bat Test\test.bat" Value1 "Val ue2"
>   ※実験1と同じコマンドライン
>   ※引数の2つめに半角スペースが入っているのもポイント
>   出力結果：
>   [image: 実験2画像]
>
> 問題が発生しています。
>   cmd.exe /c "c:\Bat Test\test.bat" Value1 "Val ue2"
>   Bat' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
>   可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
>   "の区切りがおかしくなってしまい、test.batの格納先の
>   フォルダ「Bat Test」が「Bat」で切れてしまっています。
>
> 【対処方法】
>   cmd.exe /c ""c:\Bat Test\test.bat" Value1 "Val ue2""
>   **※cmd.exe /c の後に続くコマンドラインの前後を"で更に括ります。**
>   出力結果：
>   [image: 対処結果画像]
>
> 【何故こんな事になるのかについての考察】
>   cmd.exe /cのパラメータのパース処理の仕様だとおもいます。

以下省略

---

質問のプログラムで言えば以下の行を、

```
strCommand = "/c \"C:\\Test\\Sample.bat\" " + strPath;
```

こちらのようにすれば、正常に処理されます。

```
strCommand = "/c \"\"C:\\Test\\Sample.bat\" " + strPath + "\"";
```

Unicode版ならこちら。

```
strCommand = L"/c \"\"C:\\Test\\Sample.bat\" " + strPath + L"\"";
```